# STM Nucleo-F722ZE UART weirdness when setting the baud rate (it needs to be set 3 times larger)

Tags: arduino, stm32, stm32cubemx, cortex-m, nucleo

For the past days I've been trying to communicate via UART between an Arduino and an STM32 Nucleo F722ZE board. After much troubleshooting with the oscilloscope I realized that when I set a baud rate in the Cube IDE the actual baud rate is 3 times lower. I assume that this is because of bad clock configuration but I couldn't find a reference anywhere to this.

Here is my current clock configuration inside the Cube IDE.
Did anyone encounter this before? Have I missed a part of the documentation about it? I would be grateful if someone has an explanation or a link towards the official docs detailing this. Thank you very much.
[image: My current clock configuration]
Here is the baud rate settings for communicating with a device at 9600. I have to set it to 3 * 9600 = 28800.
[image: Settings in STM32Cube for the UART port]

Comment: Check the clock frequency definition in software, and the oscillator or crystal on the PCB.

Comment: You have the external clock (HSE) configured in CubeMX as 25MHz, but according to the schematics your board has a 8MHz crystal fitted. Roughly a factor of 3...

Comment: That was it, thank you so much, I didn't even think about it and assumed the default board configuration knew the value of the oscillator. Many many thanks, you saved me a lot of frustration.